# System.ArgumentException: Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 197?

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure, azure-webjobs

So I have a console application which is running fine in local environment but when I am running to app in Azure app service as webjob then I am receiving the following error:

```
[06/28/2022 07:59:46 > fa1ef8: INFO]  System.ArgumentException: Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 197.
[06/28/2022 07:59:46 > fa1ef8: INFO]    at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.GetKeyValuePair(String connectionString, Int32 currentPosition, StringBuilder buffer, Boolean useOdbcRules, String& keyname, String& keyvalue)
[06/28/2022 07:59:46 > fa1ef8: INFO]    at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Hashtable parsetable, String connectionString, Boolean buildChain, Hashtable synonyms, Boolean firstKey)
[06/28/2022 07:59:46 > fa1ef8: INFO]    at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions..ctor(String connectionString, Hashtable synonyms, Boolean useOdbcRules)
[06/28/2022 07:59:46 > fa1ef8: INFO]    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString..ctor(String connectionString)
[06/28/2022 07:59:46 > fa1ef8: INFO]    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnectionOptions(String connectionString, DbConnectionOptions previous)
[06/28/2022 07:59:46 > fa1ef8: INFO]    at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnectionPoolGroup(DbConnectionPoolKey key, DbConnectionPoolGroupOptions poolOptions, DbConnectionOptions& userConnectionOptions)
[06/28/2022 07:59:46 > fa1ef8: INFO]    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ConnectionString_Set(DbConnectionPoolKey key)
[06/28/2022 07:59:46 > fa1ef8: INFO]    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.set_ConnectionString(String value)
[06/28/2022 07:59:46 > fa1ef8: INFO]    at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.<SetConnectionString>b__18(DbConnection t, DbConnectionPropertyInterceptionContext`1 c)
[06/28/2022 07:59:46 > fa1ef8: INFO]    at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext](TTarget target, Action`2 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
[06/28/2022 07:59:46 > fa1ef8: INFO]    at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.SetConnectionString(DbConnection connection, DbConnectionPropertyInterceptionContext`1 interceptionContext)
[06/28/2022 07:59:46 > fa1ef8: INFO]    at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.InitializeFromConnectionStringSetting(ConnectionStringSettings appConfigConnection)
[06/28/2022 07:59:46 > fa1ef8: INFO]    at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.TryInitializeFromAppConfig(String name, AppConfig config)
[06/28/2022 07:59:46 > fa1ef8: INFO]    at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.Initialize()
[06/28/2022 07:59:46 > fa1ef8: INFO]    at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.get_ProviderName()
[06/28/2022 07:59:46 > fa1ef8: INFO]    at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.get_ProviderName()
[06/28/2022 07:59:46 > fa1ef8: INFO]    at System.Data.Entity.Internal.DefaultModelCacheKeyFactory.Create(DbContext context)
[06/28/2022 07:59:46 > fa1ef8: INFO]    at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
[06/28/2022 07:59:46 > fa1ef8: INFO]    at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
[06/28/2022 07:59:46 > fa1ef8: INFO]    at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
[06/28/2022 07:59:46 > fa1ef8: INFO]    at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
[06/28/2022 07:59:46 > fa1ef8: INFO]    at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()
[06/28/2022 07:59:46 > fa1ef8: INFO]    at System.Linq.Queryable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate)
[06/28/2022 07:59:46 > fa1ef8: INFO]    at Data.Repository.Repository`1.FirstOrDefault(Expression`1 predicate) in D:\Projects\Repository\Repository.cs:line 594
[06/28/2022 07:59:46 > fa1ef8: INFO]    at ConfigurationService.GetConfigValueByConfigCode(String configType, String configCode, IUnitOfWork uow) in D:\Projects\Configurations\ConfigurationService.cs:line 159
[06/28/2022 07:59:46 > fa1ef8: INFO]    at ArchiveOldSMBFiles.Program.ProcessMethod() in D:\Projects\ArchiveOldSMBFiles\Program.cs:line 104
```

I did some research and figured out that the issue is with my database connection string. So here is the connection string in my app.config of my console application:

```
<connectionStrings>
        <add name="Entities" connectionString="data source=[Server Name];initial catalog=[Database Name];user id=[Login id];password=[Password];multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 2):

Following given format should be used for standard connection strings as per azure:

```
Server=tcp:[serverName].database.windows.net;Database=myDataBase;
User ID=[LoginForDb]@[serverName];Password=myPassword;Trusted_Connection=False;
Encrypt=True;
```

so according to this your connection string would become

```
<connectionStrings>
        <add name="Entities" connectionString="Server=tcp:[serverName].database.windows.net;Database=myDataBase;
User ID=[LoginForDb]@[serverName];Password=myPassword;Trusted_Connection=False;
Encrypt=True;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

see the link for more info
https://www.connectionstrings.com/azure-sql-database/

Comment: Its still not working properly. I am using ```Server Type : Database Engine```.

Comment: In my local machine I use VPN to connect to SQL Server after doing SQL Server Authentication